# atopsar extraction to text file with additional info

Tags: shell, awk

As part of performance metrics collections, I'm trying to get the CPU,IO,Memory... usages of system for the particular run using atop.
To achieve this, I'm starting atop to generate the atop-data file using below command

```
/usr/bin/atop -a -w /venki/atop_temp 2
```

Once the datafile is generated, I'm going to extract the interested information. For example I want to get the memory usage details. For this, I'm applying below command.

```
atopsar -b 20:39:45 -e 20:42:45 -r /venki/atop_temp -S -x -a -m > /venki/atop_mem4
```

It's resulting with below info:

```
sdl00999  2.6.32.54-0.7.TDC.1.R.4-default  #1 SMP 2012-04-19 16:07:40 +0200  x86_64  2016/11/15

-------------------------- analysis date: 2016/11/15 --------------------------
20:39:37  memtotal memfree buffers cached dirty slabmem  swptotal swpfree _mem_

20:39:41     3700M   2386M      9M   353M    0M    121M      309M    302M
20:39:43     3700M   2385M      9M   353M    0M    121M      309M    302M
20:39:47     3700M   2385M      9M   353M    2M    121M      309M    302M
20:39:49     3700M   2385M      9M   353M    2M    121M      309M    302M
```

But, I need additional column [Date - 2016/11/16] in the beginning. 
I need this information, if my test went for multiple days [3 days - I need information like, which dates time]

Can any-one help me on this

Thanks in-advance

Comment: You already have this `analysis date: 2016/11/15` in the title. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I need it like, column in the file like below:

2016/11/15   20:39:41     3700M   2386M      9M   353M    0M    121M      309M    302M

2016/11/15   20:39:43     3700M   2385M      9M   353M    0M    121M      309M    302M

2016/11/15   20:39:47     3700M   2385M      9M   353M    2M    121M      309M    302M

20:39:49     3700M   2385M      9M   353M    2M    121M      309M    302M

Comment: In real time, I'm going to have 1000's of lines, For this, I need to append date to each line after extraction. It will be easy, If it's included in extraction level.

Comment: It is easy with `awk` if you always have a like like this `----analysis date: 2016/11/15 ----`

Comment: Hi GMichael,

    Can you help me to achieve this with awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the following:

```
atopsar -b 20:39:45 -e 20:42:45 -r /venki/atop_temp -S -x -a -m | awk 'BEGIN {DATE_STAMP=""; } /analysis date: /{DATE_STAMP=$4;} /^[0-9]/ {print DATE_STAMP, $0;}' > /venki/atop_mem4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GMichael. Now, i'm done with the requirement.

Comment: Never use all upper case variables in shell or awk scripts to avoid clashing with builtin (and in shells case also exported) variables and obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using builtin/exported variables when you aren't. You can remove the BEGIN section, what it's doing is the default behavior you'd get without it. The trailing semi-colons would be needed for a C program but not for awk, you can remove those too.